# 2s complement and bitwise operations

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, twos-complement

So I'm working on some homework and am completely stumped by this current question.

`Assume that there are 73 students in your class. If every student is to be assigned a unique bit pattern, what is the minimum number of bits to this? And Why?`

I don't know how to get the solution to this, `is it 73!`? If not how do I determine this solution

THANK YOU ALL FOR THE ANSWERS....SOLVED :D

Comment: ceiling(log base 2 (73))

Comment: basic thought pattern: (2 to the power of X) >= 73, where X is an integer. solve for x

Comment: Write 73 in binary, that amount of digits is your answer.

Comment: Ok, I kind of had an idea that it would be something like 2^7 but wasn't 100% sure.

Comment: Sorry wont answer a HW question, but a good hint is that you can never have a set of bits that can represent 73 exactly even if a bit can be more than 0 or 1. For example if each bit could be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 or any other number less than 73 it would still be impossible to get exactly 73. Of course something that can do more than 73 is easy...hint hint

Comment: If the question is answered to your satisfaction you should accept that answer rather than leaving a comment in your question.

Comment: i can't for a couple more minutes @MikeW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some elegant mathematical solutions in the comments, but think of it like this:

```
1 bit gives you two possible bit patterns.
2 bits gives you four
3 bits gives you eight
.
.
.
.
```

Continue in the same vein until you have a number of bit patterns larger than the number of students.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be able to represent 73 numbers in binary. You can easily notice, that there are 73 numbers in range `[0, 72]`, so you need as many bits as you have to have to represent the number 72 in binary.

```
2^6 = 64 < 72 < 128 = 2^7
```

so you need 7 bits to represent 73 different numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Since bits can simply be thought of as binary digits, we can convert the base-10 `72` to the base-2 `1001000` and determine our answer, which is the number of digits in this base-2 number, 7. To get the number `72`, take into account that we can assign the number `0` to one of the students.

Another way to get the answer is to find the smallest `n` for which `2^n > 73`.